# Graph API: get nearby places

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to pass in lat/long and get a list of nearby places using Graph API 2.1?

Was looking to allow a user to check in from an iOS app, but I'd like to provide a list of nearby places so that I know which place ID to pass into the feed end point.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, this is possible if you can get the lat/lng coordinate from your device. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search

```
GET /search?q={query}&type=place&center={lat},{lng}&distance={distance}
```

You can leave the `{query}` blank if you don't want to narrow down your results

> All Graph API search queries require an access token included in the request.

Comment: what about access token? is it optional?

Comment: it require accesstoken . but in my app i am not using facebook login functionality . how i can fetch results https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Paris&type=place&center=48.8567,2.3508&limit=20&distance=1000

Comment: I have seen and they require access token

Comment: So it should be clear I guess... You can use an app access token as well, but you need an access token

Comment: sorry what you mean by app access token ? Secret key ?

Comment: @Tobi. The Facebook docs are terrible. You can use an app token without a user token, you need to put your app access token in you Plist under the key `FacebookClientToken`. I haven't found any documentation about being able to do this and have actually found pages in facebooks developer docs that say you can't do it!

Comment: you can copy the APP token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a request to the Facebook Graph API for location searches, you **do not** need a user Access Token, you can use your App Token, which you'll find here: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app_id}/settings/advanced` under **Client Token**

Assuming you have the facebook SDK setup correctly, all you have to do is add your App Token to your `info.plist` under the key `FacebookClientToken`. Now you should be able to make Graph Location API requests without authorizing a user!

This is what your `info.plist` should look like:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>{{APP_ID}}</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>{{CLIENT_TOKEN}}</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>{{APP_NAME}}</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Obviously, change anything between the {{ }} to the appropriate value.